# Local Chromecast receiver not loading

Tags: python, macos, chromecast, receiver

I am developing a Chromecast app and currently host it locally for development purpose.

It used to work fine when I had an internal ip set as my receiver url (http://192.168.1.167:9000/receiver.html) and hosted a server on my Windows machine using

```
python -m http.server 9000.
```

Now my laptop broke and I'm working on a mac mini (also because i was going to develop an iOS sender app for my receiver anyway) so I'm trying to get the receiver hosted on the mac mini.

I'm using the same principe, internal ip of the mac-mini set as receiver url, started a server using

```
Python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000.
```

When I try to connect to my receiver, I can't get it to load.

The Chromecast displays:
Cannot load sources (or some other english equivalent of my dutch error: 'De bronnen kunnen niet geladen worden'.)

I forwarded a port in my router to my receiver and I can reach it from outside my own network (mobile 4g), I can reach it internally, colleagues can reach it, it's just the Chromecast which somehow refuses to load the page and I can't figure out why.
The Android SDK gives me CastStatusCode.CANCELED and iOS SDK GCKErrorCodeCancelled.

I also tried to update Python to the latest version, but it didn't fix it.

The Chromecast loads other apps fine, I can ping to the Chromecast and to my devices. When the Chromecast attempts to load the app, I can briefly load the debugger but it doesn't display anything in either network or console.

I hope someone has had a similair issue or any clue on how I can get the Chromecast to connect to my server again.

Answer (score 2):

Of all the things i tried the last couple of hours, I didn't think of the basic 'Have you tried rebooting it'....

Cause was firmware update...